# WinRT: ItemsControl OnItemChanged event is Windows Runtime Object

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, itemscontrol

I'm trying to write custom universal app ItemsControl and I depend in OnItemsChaned event. I expected to get some info about the event type (add,reset, and so on) and index, but the only thing I get is Windows Runtime Object derived from System.__ComObject. But in debugger this object actually has the necessary properties, but how do I access them? Thanks a lot.

```
public sealed class MyOwnControl: ItemsControl
{
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(object e)
    {
        // Works but has not all the information
        IVectorChangedEventArgs vectorChangedArgs = (IVectorChangedEventArgs)e;            

        // Should work but does not
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs collectionChangedEventargs = (NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)e;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that object can be cast to IVectorChangedEventArgs to get the exact values of Index and Action, but I don't actually know if it does work all the time and if it's always this type

Comment: You can predict the Add, Remove actions by maintaining the Items.Count in  a variable internally. Whenever OnItemsChanged is invoked compare your internal count and identify the action.

Comment: Yep, but I can't see replace, move actions, too.

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem and think that is a Windows 8 bug. I have added some code  for better understanding the problem. Weird...